# Remove inner part of url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to strip the word 'category' from https://www.domain.nl/producten/category/itemname so that when somebody visits that url, he/she will be redirected to https://www.domain.nl/producten/itemname. Itemname will be different every time.

I tried several things I found here at Stackoverflow but they don't seem to work. Has anybody got an idea of how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/producten/category/itemname/?$ /producten/itemname
```

For dynmic paths, you can use :

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2
```

$n is part of the regex, it's the part matched between ([^/]+), $1 here, contains the value  **producten** and $2 contains **itemname**

Source :

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works, but it's too agressive: it removes all second folders. I tried to change your code to only remove the word 'category' in a dynamic path (always the second value in the url) but to not do anything if the word 'category' isn't present, but I can't get it to work. I have never worked with Regex before, sorry if my questions are stupid. Can you help me further along?